# Django vs Opencart, etc

Tags: django, content-management-system, e-commerce

What are **advantages** of using Django instead E-commerce/CMS systems on php?
I want to make an e-commerce site for a clothing store with Django, but I'm interested to know why should I use the framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can use Python-libraries. That is an advantage, because there are Python-libraries for just about everything immaginable. Especially if you want to build your own analytics, because there are many data-science libraries written in or for Python.

Also on a more subjective level Python's syntax is nicer than PHP's, but that's just an opinion.

Edit: you might be interested in https://www.django-cms.org/en/